# <img> placement in a rows depending on window's width

Tags: html, css

I have a set of images of the same size.
I want to display them as a table-like structure, but to change number of "columns", depending on user's browser's window width, with all structure being centered.
What i've come up with is this: http://jsfiddle.net/MHva2/3/.

```
.container {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

.element {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

<div class = "container">
    <img class = "element" />
    <img class = "element" />
</div>
```

Which works only when all images can be placed in a single row.
Once line "breaks", the `container` element takes all free place, like that: http://jsfiddle.net/MHva2/5/.
Is there a way to make it flow around its content in this situatuon?

**UPDATE:**
I'll try to explain.
What i want is for browser to place images automatically in a container, in which they should look like table cells, with the number of columns equal to `floor(window_width / image_width)`.
Number of images may vary and whole table-like construction should be centered.
I've drawn a picture, showing how the same page with the same number of images should look inside differently sized windows: http://rghost.net/44024115.view.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please elaborate it

Answer (score 1):

@milind_developer is correct, your question is poorly worded, and could certainly use more detail.

From what I gather you are wanting a flexible number of columns, that will expand/contract with the size of the users viewport?

To do this you could create a column class like:

```
.example-column {
    float: left;
}
```

Then enclose whatever elements you wish inside the columns:

```
 <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="example-column">
                <div class="element"></div>
                <div class="element"></div>
                <div class="element"></div>
           </div>
           <div class="example-column">
                <div class="element"></div>
                <div class="element"></div>
                <div class="element"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The float style gives a basic level of fluid layout, but you may also wish to exert great precision over the behavior of the columns through the use of media queries, e.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   .example-column {
        float: none;
    } 
}
```

This would force anything under 500px to use one column layout (if you want greater control use ID's).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MHva2/8/